# Is there a way to copy subfolder without copying recursively?

Tags: python, shutil

Am trying to copy subdirectories from directory but I realize the first subfolder copied is copied 'recursively'. I would not like that. I would like to copy the sub folder intactly.

```
import os
import shutil

#---- Create the directries

 os.makedirs("Test/Dir-A/Sub-dir-A")
 os.makedirs("Test/Dir-A/Sub-dir-B")
 os.makedirs("Test/Dir-B/Sub-dir-A")
 os.makedirs("Test/Dir-B/Sub-dir-B")
 os.makedirs("Test/Dir-C/Sub-dir-A")
 os.makedirs("Test/Dir-C/Sub-dir-B")

selectdirs = ["Dir-A", "Dir-B"]

alldirs = os.listdir("Test")

specificcourses = [folder for folder in alldirs if folder in selectdirs]

for f in specificcourses:
    shutil.move(os.path.join("Test", f), os.path.join("Test", "New-dir"))
```

When I run the code, I have Sub-dir-A, Sub-dir-B and Dir-B copied in New-dir. I however want Dir-A and Dir-B in New-dir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import os
import re

#---- Create the directries

try:
    os.makedirs("Test/Dir-A/Sub-dir-A")
    os.makedirs("Test/Dir-A/Sub-dir-B")
    os.makedirs("Test/Dir-B/Sub-dir-A")
    os.makedirs("Test/Dir-B/Sub-dir-B")
    os.makedirs("Test/Dir-C/Sub-dir-A")
    os.makedirs("Test/Dir-C/Sub-dir-B")
except:
    pass

sub = (os.walk("Test"))

try:
    os.mkdir("NewDir")
except:
    pass

for f in sub:
    for s in f[1]:
        os.mkdir(re.sub("^Test", "NewDir", os.path.join(f[0], s)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that your "New-dir" exists before copying.

This works as you may want:

```
import os
import shutil

#---- Create the directries

os.makedirs("Test/Dir-A/Sub-dir-A")
os.makedirs("Test/Dir-A/Sub-dir-B")
os.makedirs("Test/Dir-B/Sub-dir-A")
os.makedirs("Test/Dir-B/Sub-dir-B")
os.makedirs("Test/Dir-C/Sub-dir-A")
os.makedirs("Test/Dir-C/Sub-dir-B")

selectdirs = ["Dir-A", "Dir-B"]

alldirs = os.listdir("Test")

specificcourses = [folder for folder in alldirs if folder in selectdirs]

os.makedirs("Test/New-dir")
for f in specificcourses:
    input()
    shutil.move(os.path.join("Test", f), os.path.join("Test", "New-dir"))
```